# Правильно ли построена конструкция с в том числе?

Tags: грамматика, союзы, правила

Фонд осуществляет:
<...>
7) предоставление государственных гарантий, мер социальной защиты (поддержки), социальных услуг отдельным категориям граждан, **в том числе** в рамках оказания государственной социальной помощи.

Уважаемые лингвисты, филологи! Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли в приведенной конструкции нарушение при употреблении союза *в том числе*? В чем это нарушение выражается. Как можно изложить по-другому, учитывая особенности функционирования языка закона.